# WIndow 8 Store App auto load image from local

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1

I use camera capture a photo and save it into my local, then I click the back button back to MainPage, I want the captured photo displayed in my main page. I use the following code in my main page:

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter as StorageFile;

    if (parameter != null)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("CapturedImage.jpeg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        finalImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uri); 
    }
}
```

The error message is "An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code".How to I solve it? Thanks

Comment: `"CapturedImage.jpeg"` is not a valid absolute uri. It's at most a relative one.

Comment: I have try both "Relative" and "RelativeOrAbsolute". But also cannot.

Comment: Where are you saving the image after capturing?

Comment: I run the simulator in my pc, the saving location is "Picture Library".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = e.Parameter as StorageFile;

    if (parameter != null)
    {
        using (var strm = await parameter.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(strm);
            finalImage.Source = bmp;
        }
    }
}
```

`Uri` works only for these scenarios.

- If file is in local, roaming or temp directory, use `Uri` as `ms-appdata:///local/CapturedImage.jpeg` or `ms-appdata:///roaming/CapturedImage.jpeg`
- If file is part of package, use `Uri` as `ms-appx:///YOUR_FOLDER/CapturedImage.jpeg`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code have error message "Cannot Implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'". If I use Uri as ms-appdata:///local/CapturedImage.jpeg or ms-appdata:///roaming/CapturedImage.jpeg, no error but cannot load image.